# How to find first element before another element

Tags: jquery

I need to get the id of a element which has the possibilities of unlimited child's. If the user clicked on each element inside this (main element) then i need to now the id of main-element to insert a new div before or after that element.

Example

```
<div id="contentholder" data-ownid="100">
...
- add here a new div on click at each of the children from the main-element
<div id="999" data-ownid="1">
This is the main-element
   <div id="a" data-ownid="2"></div>
   <div id="b" data-ownid="3"><div><span id="d" data-ownid="5"></span></div></div>
   <div id="c" data-ownid="4"><img id="f" data-ownid="6"...><span id="g" data-ownid="7"></span></div>
   <img id="h" data-ownid="8"...>
</div>
- or add here a new div on click at each of the children from the main-element
...
</div>
```

I know to add the new div, by

```
$('#ID').before('<div>newdiv</div>');
```

and

```
$('#ID').after('<div>newdiv</div>'); //formatting
```

Important to know, is that the div id=999 is not the last parent. It is also a child of unknown numbers of elements before. So my search have to stop at this div to get this ID.

Maybe its a way to look for the last parent before the div with id=contentholder?
The contentholder ist the last parent of all for this set.

How i get the ID for the main-element by click on a nested element?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$(this).closest('[id]').attr('id')`

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i dont understand the way you suggest it. i don't know the [id]!?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `[id]` selector if just your required elements has `id`s

```js
$(document).on('click' , '*:not([id])' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log($(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentholder">
  <div id="888">
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
  <div id="999">
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

- `[id]` selector to select the element which has `id` attribute
- [`e.stopPropagation`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
- `*:not([id])` select all elements but NOT the ones which has an `id`

**Update code** using `data` attribute

```js
$(document).on('click' , '*:not([data-id])' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log($(this).closest('[data-id]').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentholder">
  <div id="888" data-id>
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
  <div id="999" data-id>
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Be sure when you add a new div you add to it the `data-id` attribute

```
$('#ID').before('<div data-id>newdiv</div>');
```

**This is How it works without `id` or `data` attribute**

```js
$(document).on('click' , '*:not(#contentholder > div)' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).attr('data-get-parent' , '');  // add data attribute to the clicked element
  console.log($('#contentholder > div:has([data-get-parent])').attr('id'));  // get id of the direct div of #contentholder which has the appended data attribute
  $('[data-get-parent]').removeAttr('data-get-parent'); // remove the data attribute
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentholder">
  <div id="888">
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
  <div id="999">
  This is the main-element
     <div></div>
     <div><div><span>Span</span></div></div>
     <div><img src=""/><span>Span</span></div>
     <img/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

- `>` in selector means direct child
- `:has()` select element which has(element) 

  The expression $( "div:has(p)" ) matches a  if a

  exists anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

Comment: if i understand your code right, it only works, if the other elements has no id attribute. Thats not correctly, i update my code for this point.

Comment: yes @MikeR I got the point .. in this case you can use `data-id` attribute for the elements you want then use `[data-id]` instead of `[id]` ..

Comment: ok, but let me ask is there no way to look for the first element before "contentholder" starting by the clicked element and go upside?

Comment: @MikeR give me sometime to find a way for what you want .. maybe a long way but i'll see

Comment: @MikeR answer Updated

Comment: @MikeR make sure the `newdiv` has an id otherwise the code will return undefined

Comment: great, i think we are close to the end. i've add now a data-ownid to every element. if i try with your code $('#contentholder> div:has(['+$(this).attr('data-ownid')+'])').attr('id') i recieved "undefined", in the $(this).attr('data-ownid') is the id of the element. i update my code again.

Comment: No @MikeR I meant add the `data` attribute for just the required elements not all .. 2nd: I updated my answer with the code so you don't have to use `[id]` or even `[data]` .. 3rd: in a selector nothing called `:has(['+$(this).attr('data-ownid')+'])'` it should be `:has([data-ownid])'` .. `$(this).attr('data-ownid')` will return the value of the `data`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add some identifier with data attribute for example `data-parent="999"` and then use click handler where you want inside of a click handler get your parent element with `var $parent = $(this).closest('[data-parent]');`. Then you can get any information you want about that element and use `` $('<div>I`m a freshly generated element</div>').insertAfter($parent); ``.

Comment: ok, but let me ask is there no way to look for the first element before "contentholder" starting by the clicked element and go upside?

Comment: You can either by using ```$('#contentholder').first();```, but I prefer more specific solution if you need certain element ```$('#contentholder').find('[data-parent]').get(0)```

Comment: @vytsci tag him to get notified by typing `@` then his name :)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef thanks for advise :D thought people gets noticed anyway.

Comment: @vytsci yes, thanks a lot, i post my way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

After great suggestion from @Mohamed-Yousef i decide to create a smal nested function to loop the elements till the end.

This no need to add and remove a new data-attr and works in every consterlation wich all kind of elements.

Here it is:

```
function get_first(element)
  {
        function is_parent(element)
        {
              if($(element).parent().attr('id') !='contentholder')
              {     return is_parent('#'+$(element).parent().attr('id'));                         
              }else{      return res=$(element).attr('data-editor-id');   }
        }            
        return is_parent(element);
  }
```